# Angular2 npm install error

Tags: angular, npm, package.json

this is my package.json and error log

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "keywords": [
    "angular",
    "charts",
    "highcharts"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.4",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.4",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.4",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.4.4",
    "angular2-highcharts": "^0.5.5",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-select": "^1.12.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^1.6.6",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.3",
    "systemjs": "0.20.0",
    "zone.js": "0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "3.1.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "2.1.5",
    "typings": "^1.4.0",
    "@types/highcharts": "^4.2.47",
    "highcharts": "^5.0.7"
  },
    "repository": {}
}

npm WARN lifecycle Test2.0@1.0.0~postinstall: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) 
Test@1.0.0 typings install /data/Test/app
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN Test@1.0.0 No description
```

Is my angular2 version wrong???
how can i fix it ..
when i run angular2 with my flask app got error too

```
Error: Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the module 'AppModule'
        at SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://test.testurl.com/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1596:31)
        at new SyntaxError (http://test.testurl.com/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1794:20)
        at eval (http://test.testurl.com/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:18119:44)
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://test.testurl.com/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:18117:58)
        at JitCompiler._loadModules (http://test.testurl.com/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:27145:68)
        at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://test.testurl.com/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:27105:56)
        at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://test.testurl.com/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:27071:25)
        at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (http://test.testurl.com/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8579:29)
        at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (http://test.testurl.com/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8554:25)
    Evaluating http://test.testurl.com/static/ts/main.js
    Error loading http://test.testurl.com/static/ts/main.js
```

it works well in my local but i cannot load angular2 in ubuntu.

++ my app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';
import { TestApp}   from './TestApp.component';
import { Splitter, SplitArea }   from './base/Splitter.component';
import { TabPanel, Tab }   from './base/TabPanel.component';
import { SideBar }   from './SideBar.component';
import { ArticleListView ,ArticleItem ,SearchComponent,ArticleDetail,Pagination}   from './ArticleListView.component';
import { TrendGraphView, ArticleCountGraphView }   from './TrendGraphView.component';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {AlertModule,ButtonsModule,PaginationModule} from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        AlertModule.forRoot(),
        RouterModule.forRoot([
          {
            path: 'page',
            component: Pagination
          }
        ]),
        ButtonsModule.forRoot(),
        PaginationModule.forRoot(),
        ChartModule.forRoot(require('highcharts')) 
        ],
    declarations: [
                    TestApp,
                    Splitter, SplitArea,
                    TabPanel, Tab,
                    SideBar,
                    ArticleListView,
                    ArticleItem,
                    SearchComponent,
                    ArticleDetail,
                    Pagination,
                    TrendGraphView,
                    ArticleCountGraphView
    ],
    bootstrap: [ TestApp]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: ++ is app.module.ts wrong in flask error??

Comment: Show us your `AppModule` code please

Comment: @SrAxi i edit appmodule code in body

Comment: Is `testApp` an exported component? Is it defined? Could we see the code of that? The thing is that your `AppModule` is trying to declare something that is `undefined`. And I strongly believe is that `testApp`.

Comment: @SrAxi

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

enum ContentViewType {
 ArticleList,
 TrendGraph
}

@Component({
 selector: 'TestApp',
 templateUrl: './static/ts/TestApp.component.html'
})

export class TestApp {
 public ContentViewType = ContentViewType;

 contentViewType = ContentViewType.ArticleList;
}

Comment: @SrAxi testApp is a typing error it is TestApp